# How can I consume a web service with Play Framework 2 when the url has a colon in it?

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

This url works fine when I try it in my browser:

```
https://username:password@api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$top=3
```

But when I run this code:

```
Promise<WS.Response> page = WS.url("https://username:password@api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$top=3").get();
```

I get this exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL: https://username:password@api.prosper.com/api/Listings
```

I discovered that if I remove the colon from between username and password it doesn't throw an exception.

So I tried escaping the colon like this and got the same exception:

```
Promise<WS.Response> page = WS.url("https://username%3Apassword@api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$top=3").get();
```

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested, but it should work this way:

```
WSRequestHolder requestHolder = WS.url("https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$top=3");
requestHolder.setAuth("username", "password");
Promise<Response> promise = requestHolder.get();
```

Comment: Which all header files do I need to import. I am getting too many options.